# Monotouch: how to add UIView to DialogViewController

Tags: uiview, xamarin.ios, dialogviewcontroller

In one of my screens I need to add UIView (with some labels and buttons) to DialogViewController. The reason is I'm not using TableView header for this is that I don't want this view to scroll when table is scrolled.

I can achieved this if I add my custom view to navigation bar, but then my view won't receive any touches (navigation controller eats them).

I've also tried adding custom view to DialogsViewController parent controller and while it works, resizing the frame of tableview in LoadView() doesn't do anything.

Is there any other ways of adding custom view to DialogViewController?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

To add a header that doesn't scroll you could create a controller whose view contains both the  additional views you want to add as well as the DialogViewController's view. For example the following simple example adds a UILabel along with the DialogViewController's view as subviews of an additional controller (called *container* in this case):

```
   [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        UIWindow window;
        MyDialogViewController dvc;
        UIViewController container;
        float labelHeight = 30;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            container = new UIViewController ();

            container.View.AddSubview (new UILabel (new RectangleF (0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, labelHeight)){
                Text = "my label", BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green});

            dvc = new MyDialogViewController (labelHeight);

            container.View.AddSubview (dvc.TableView);

            window.RootViewController = container;

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }

    }
```

Then the DialogViewController adjusts the TableView's height in the ViewDidLoad method:

```
   public partial class MyDialogViewController : DialogViewController
    {
        float labelHeight;

        public MyDialogViewController (float labelHeight) : base (UITableViewStyle.Grouped, null)
        {
            this.labelHeight = labelHeight;

            Root = new RootElement ("MyDialogViewController") {
                new Section (){
                    new StringElement ("one"),
                    new StringElement ("two"),
                    new StringElement ("three")
                }
            };
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            TableView.Frame = new RectangleF (TableView.Frame.Left, TableView.Frame.Top + labelHeight, TableView.Frame.Width, TableView.Frame.Height - labelHeight);
        }
    }
```

Here's a screenshot showing the result in the simulator:
[image]